# Disabling COLUMN UPDATES in Change Tracking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, change-tracking

I have enabled Change Tracking with the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
```

However, I noticed that `TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON` creates overhead, also, my dev team is not using that feature. 
How can I set `TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = OFF`? I don't want to disable/enable change tracking, which might cause loss of change tracking data.

I was expecting something like below:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = OFF)
```

But it's not the right syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently you can't: once you enable `CHANGE_TRACKING` in SSMS the `TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED` option is greyed out:

[image]

Here is another confirmation from [this](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2-introducing-change-tracking-part-1-3/) blog:

> TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED property is optional. If set to ON, it is possible to find out which individual columns will be affected by each UPDATE operation: if omitted, its value is OFF (the default); **be careful because, once Change Tracking is enabled, you cannot change the value of this option**. If you do wish to change it, you must disable CT on the table and repeat the enabling procedure.

Comment: Andrea, Thank you so much!